# how to check which Input checkBox tag changed with value in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In the below given code, i can randomly check or uncheck any number  of checkboxes.

```
    <button class="button" type="button">Device 1</button>
   &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input name="device1" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]={{device1}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
 <br/> <button  class="button" type="button">Device 2</button>
    &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input name="device2" type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]={{device2}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
   <br/> <button class="button" type="button">Device 3</button>
    &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input  name="device3" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]={{device3}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)" >
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
   <br/> <button  class="button" type="button">Device 4</button>
    &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input  name="device4" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]={{device4}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
  <br/>  <button class="button" type="button">Device 5</button>
    &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input name="device5" type="checkbox"[(ngModel)]={{device5}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
  <br/>  <button class="button" type="button">Device 6</button>
    &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input  name="device6" type="checkbox"[(ngModel)]={{device6}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
  <br/>  <button class="button" type="button">Device 7</button>
    &nbsp; <label class="switch">
  <input name="device7" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]={{device7}} (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event)">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
  </div>
export class DashboardComponent{


    OnInput(value:any){
        console.log(value);
    }
```

i want to know which input tag is being selected with value ...and want to get only  changed checkboxes details with Input name and value

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the angular2's named identifier/reference `#the_name` to each input and pass it in the method:

```
  <input name="device1" type="checkbox" 
   #device1
   [(ngModel)]={{device1}} 
   (ngModelChange)="OnInput($event, device1)"><!--pass it here-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ngModelChange**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="object.selected" (ngModelChange)="onChange(object.selected)">
```

On the call of onChange reset the counter for the value

Comment: can you  eloborate ...how to get which input tag changed ...what should be Onchange function

Comment: the object.selected gives you the input checked. Then you can create a jquery function in the component that will do the operations you require